# allocating double pointer in a function return segfault in main

Tags: c, pointers

I have created a double int pointer in main and called a function where I allocate place for this pointer.

```
void foo(int **array)
{
    int i, j;
    array = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*(100)); //rows

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(50)); //cols

    array[0][0] = 10;
}
```

and in main I have just these lines;

```
int** array;

foo(array);

printf("%d \n", array[0][0]);
```

As a result I get a segmentation fault. Since I am passing a pointer and it is allocated in `foo` method, does it mean that in `main` method it is not allocated? How can I solve it without making `foo` function to return a double pointer?

Comment: There are tons of duplicates, search for *pass by reference in c*.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Why not just return the pointer? Your function is `void`.

Comment: And **always** check for error conditions!

Comment: In case you are unaware, you can avoid all this crud by writing `int (*array)[50] = malloc( sizeof(int[100][50]) );`

Answer (score 2):

The way your function is defined:

```
void foo(int **array);
```

the two-dimensional array is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the function. You will lose the allocated memory and your `main` function won't know about the allocated memory, because the `array` in `foo` and `main` are different.

One solution is to create an `int **` in `main` and then pass a pointer to that in `foo`:

```
void foo(int ***array);
```

You can then update the local variable in `main` via the pointer passed to `foo`, `*array`;

Another solution is to return the freshly allocated memory from the function:

```
int **foo(void);
```

This is a frequent question here and there should be plenty of code examples for array allocation.

Answer (score 0):

finally, check this. update your foo function as below and it should work as per your expectations,

```
void foo(int (***array))
{
    int i;

     *array = (int **) malloc(100*sizeof(int *)); //rows

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        (*array)[i] = malloc(50*sizeof(int));} //cols

    *array[0][0] =10;
}
```

In the main function, pass the address of array variable.

```
foo(&array);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: in the question he clearly states that he doesn't want to return a pointer for some purpose, I had given the returning version of the code, now updated it to suit his requirement.

Comment: Clearly the asker doesn't understand what he is doing

Comment: I agree with you though